# Get Environment Variable From DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, environment-variables

In my ASP.Net Core project:

1. I set Environment Variable in `launchSettings.json` with [DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/host-startup-hook.md) to load dll files.
2. I use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS")` to check what I get from DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS acutally.
3. After I changed IDE from VS2019 to VS2022. Without any changing on my project, I found that `DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS` loads 2 following files which I didn't set in `launchSettings.json`.

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\SDK\6.0.201\DotnetTools\dotnet-watch\6.0.201-servicing.22124.17\tools\net6.0\any\middleware\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll;`

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Browser Link\Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll`

Does anyone know what happended and how to let DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS stop to call these 2 files?

Thank you...

Comment: One is for [BrowserLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to other to support `dotnet-watch`. They get injected (into the env var) by VS to allow this feature to work. The "startup hooks" feature is not exclusively for your needs but used by other tools (here VS) as well. Why is this a problem for your application? What are you actually trying to do? This sounds like an  [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thank for your advice! It's not a problem actually. I just tried to study the unknown things when I tested the function for `DOTNET_STARTUP_HOOKS`

Comment: This seems to be related to the IDE starting the web project, that is, the browser is called every time it is run. You can try publishing the program and check the log to see if these two dlls still exist.